# SQL-Identify and fix criss cross records

Tags: sql

I have a table of program members with incorrect data I am trying to fix programmatically.
The following query exposes the records that need to be fixed.

```
select a.*
from Table a
join Table b
on a.BillingMemberID = b.MemberID
where a.MemberID = b.BillingMemberID 
and a.MemberID != a.BillingMemberID
```

Example data would be:

```
MemberID | BillingMemberID
1        | 1
2        | 7               <== MemberID and BillingMemberID of 2 & 7 criss cross
3        | 4               <== MemberID and BillingMemberID of 3 & 4 criss cross
4        | 3
5        | 6               <== MemberID and BillingMemberID of 5 & 6 criss cross
6        | 5
7        | 2
8        | 8
```

The fixed data would look like:

```
MemberID | BillingMemberID
1        | 1
2        | 2
3        | 3
4        | 3
5        | 5
6        | 5
7        | 2
8        | 8
```

Taking the lowest ID number of the crossed pairs and changing the BillingMemberID of the other record.
How would I write a SQL script to go through a table of 5K+ records, find these crossed pairs and fix them as shown?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your query is wrong in that in your where clause a.MemberID probably equals b.MemberID, but the second part is correct - finding the mismatches.  I assume neither example you gave actually results from your query either.

I've simplified the example to be a single table - you can extrapolate to something more complex, but it'd just be the following.  Note that it gives the full table, not just the items need fixing (you could add a clause of a.BillingMemberID != b.BillingMemberId to filter).

```sql
select a.MemberId, case when a.BillingMemberID > b.BillingMemberID then 
b.BillingMemberID else a.BillingMemberID end newval from @t1 a
inner join @t1 b
on a.BillingMemberID = b.MemberID
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description I believe that you need to update the rows where MemberID< BillingMemberID. Below script will do the work for you.(I believe it is just one table)

```
UPDATE <table_Name>
   SET BillingMemberID=MemberID
 WHERE MemberID<BillingMemberID
```